# Как чистить куки сайта в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Отправляю запросы на сайт через fetch в гугл хроме (через темпер манки) и мне нужно чистить куки после каждого запроса. Подскажите, как лучше это сделать

Comment: брать все куки и ставить им expires прошедшим временем

Comment: @InDevX я просто вообще не знаю, как работать с куки

Comment: [Так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/12593651), например.